# Read request body after JSONException

Tags: json, grails

I have a Grails controller that accepts POST requests with a JSON body. In some requests the JSON is not well formed and I get a JSONException. How could I get the request body text to log it or inspect it (I don't always have access to the client)? Grails `request.JSON` has already consumed the stream so it looks like I can't access it through request.body.

Here is my controller action:

```
def setScore(ScoreCommand scoreCommand) {
   try {
      def context = request.JSON.optJSONObject("context")
      userService.updateContext(context)
   } catch (ConverterException ce) {
      log.error("Error parsing JSON")
      // I want to log the malformed JSON body
   }
   def scoreResponse
   if (!scoreCmd.validate()) {
      scoreResponse = errorResponse(scoreCommand)
   } else {
      def scoreResult = gameService.setScore(scoreCommand)
      scoreResponse = buildResponse(scoreResult)
   }
   render scoreResponse as JSON
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work :( Unfortunately, "context" is in the body of the POST request, not in the parameters.

Comment: `log.error("Error parsing JSON", ce)` ?

Comment: Oh, it works Isammoc. As simple as that. If you put it as an answer I can set it as accepted. The full message contains the JSONException and that the malformed JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
def json = request.JSON

try {
  def context = json.optJSONObject("context")
  userService.updateContext(context)
}catch(e) {
  log.error json.toString()
}
```

Comment: Tried it and no. As soon as I access 'request.JSON' it tries to parse it and throws the exception.